Android ndk-vsomeip configuration file
In someip android example in internal_android.hpp file there is a variable named VSOMEIP_ENV_CONFIGURATION
enter image description here
i set an environment variable for the configuration file .json and its not working what should i do ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
